# creating a .so file for linux/aio_abi.h

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, embedded-linux

I am trying to build a Linux uImage and device tree for the zynq but my computer cant find the aio_abi.h file. I have moved the Linux folder which contains the file into the shared library folder that my system is looking but the file is still not being found. I think this is because there is no .so file for the folder containing the aio_abi file. I installed libaio-dev using the Ubuntu software installer tool because get-apt isn't working on my machine because of a proxy.

Is there a way to directly create a .so file for the folder I need to include or is there something wrong with the libaio-dev install? I have an older libaio1.so file but the older version doesn't contain the aio_abi file required.

Thanks

Comment: You are *very* confused. If your compiler can't find `aio_abi.h`, creating a `.so` will *not* solve that. You should edit your question to describe exactly what "my computer can't find ..." means. As is, your question is useless.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was clear. I am trying to compile a program I got from the national instruments website. When running the make file an error occurs saying "file not found <aio_abi.h> included from files" and lists a bunch of files that require it.

From looking into the problem I found that it might be that aio_abi.h is not in the correct folder my machine is looking at for libraries. I added the path to the folder containing uio to the list of search paths but when list the libraries that my computer has lib uio is not listed.